# Is there a way to put the generated files in a separate folder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, build-runner

In my app, I use freezed with json_serializable. In the folder, where I put all my data models a lot of generated files, like `model.g.dart`, `model.freeezed.dart`. Is there any possibility to move all generated files like that to a separate folder in the project, like `generated`?

Comment: Did you find the way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordint to the [build_runner documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#creating-an-output-directory)

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --output <dirname>
```

or

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --output models:<directory name>
```

to output only the **models** directory

Comment: Can't figure out how to use it. I have file lib/model.dart and I want file model.g.dart to be inside /lib/adapters/ directory, but `build --output adapters` creates packages in the root of my project with test, packages etc...

Comment: @anber did you try to pass /lib/adapters instead of adapters?

Comment: Yes, I tried lib/adapters, /lib/adapters, ./lib/adapters but was not successful

Comment: This creates an entire project inside the output folder and not just the generated files

Answer (score 5):

Here's working example from [stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889545/is-there-a-build-extensions-rule-in-build-yaml-to-output-all-generated-flutter-m):

Basically create build.yaml file like this, it will generate files in `generated` folder:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/{{}}.g.dart'
      freezed|freezed:
        enabled: true
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/{{}}.freezed.dart'
```

Don't forget to add `generated` to `part`.

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'generated/person.g.dart';
part 'generated/person.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  const factory Person({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required int age,
  }) = _Person;

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
  => _$PersonFromJson(json);
}
```