# Is there a build_extensions rule in build.yaml to output all generated Flutter models in a common directory?

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, json-serializable, build-runner

I am trying to create a `build_extensions` rule in `build.yaml` for builders [`freezed`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) and [`json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to output all generated models in the directory `lib/generated/model`, irrespective of their original location that matches `lib/**/*.dart`.

What I have tried:

- I would expect `'^lib/**/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{}}.g.dart'` to work, but it doesn't match any Dart files.
- I also tried things like `'^lib/{{path}}/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{file}}.g.dart'` but `{{path}}` needs to be matched again in the destination, as per [documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/writing_a_builder.md) (why even enforce this?).

Example:

- Base model location: `lib/core/feature/profile/profile.dart`
- Generated outputs after calling `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`:

  - `lib/generated/model/profile.g.dart`
  - `lib/generated/model/profile.freezed.dart`

My current `build.yaml` (which generates `.g.dart` and `.freezed.dart` files in the child `generated` directory relative to the original model location) is as follows:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart
        options:
          build_extensions:
            # I want this line to "work":
            # '^lib/**/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{}}.g.dart'
            'lib/{{path}}/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/{{path}}/generated/{{file}}.g.dart'
      freezed:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            # I want this line to "work":
            # '^lib/**/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{}}.freezed.dart'
            'lib/{{path}}/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/{{path}}/generated/{{file}}.freezed.dart'
          field_rename: snake
          explicit_to_json: true
      json_serializable:
        options:
          field_rename: snake
          explicit_to_json: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a similar solution, turns out it's not possible to place multiple generated outputs into the same directory.

Build extensions need to be written in a way that prevents two different files from emitting the same output file (e.g. if you had `lib/a/foo.dart` and `lib/b/foo.dart`, there can't be a single `foo.g.dart` in `lib/generated/model`). `**` is not something build extensions supports, and `{{}}` should be used to match multiple chars and then used again in the destination directory. Apart from that, build extensions just match suffixes.

To avoid the problem of different source directories potentially conflicting in the output directory, you'd have to use something like `lib/generated/model/{{path}}/{{file}}.g.dart`, there's no way to put everything in a single directory, even if you make sure that no generated files will be outputted with the same name in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

I have solve that problem. you can use this solution for your problem

```
    targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        generate_for:
          - lib/models/entities/**.dart
        options:
          build_extensions:
            # I want this line to "work":
            # '^lib/**/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{}}.g.dart'
            'lib/{{path}}/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/{{path}}/generated/{{file}}.g.dart'
      freezed:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            # I want this line to "work":
            # '^lib/**/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/model/{{}}.freezed.dart'
            'lib/{{path}}/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/{{path}}/generated/{{file}}.freezed.dart'
          field_rename: snake
          explicit_to_json: true
      json_serializable:
        options:
          field_rename: snake
          explicit_to_json: true
```